# NVL2 equivalent in criteria

Tags: sql, hibernate, nvl

I have a sql query like the below one

```
select name, loc, status, proj, nbr, sum(sub) as sub, nvl2(val, ''Y'', ''N'') where name = "value" group by name, loc, status, proj, nbr, nvl2(val, ''Y'', ''N'')
```

I tried to write the same using criteria

```
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.sum("sub"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("name", StringUtils.appendWildCard("value")).ignoreCase());              
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("value"));
```

I want to know how to write coalesce for nvl and also if the order of lines are correct.
Any leads ?

Comment: Is your SQL query a working version? Because you are retrieving columns in the select clause which are not included in the group by clause.

Comment: @Madhu I have updated it. I missed to add those. Yes the query is working and in the group by clause all the columns in the select clause are included.

Comment: any luck with my answer below @sahana?

Comment: @Madhu I have just started trying. Will let tell you soon. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Projections.sqlGroupProjection(...)` along with Criteria as below

```
    List<CoalesceDemo> list = session.createCriteria(CoalesceDemo.class).
        setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                .add(Projections.sum("sub"))
                .add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("nvl2(val, 'Y', 'N') as decodedVal", "nvl2(val, 'Y', 'N')", 
new String [] {"decodedVal"}, new Type[]{BooleanType.INSTANCE}))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("name"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("val"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("nbr"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("proj"))
                .add(Projections.groupProperty("loc")))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "value")).list();
```

resulted in following query that you are looking for:

```
select this_.name as y0_, this_.loc as y1_, this_.nbr as y2_, this_.proj as y3_, sum(this_.sub) as y4_, 
nvl2(val, 'Y', 'N') as decodedVal, this_.name as y6_, this_.val as y7_, this_.nbr as y8_, 
this_.proj as y9_, this_.loc as y10_ from CoalesceTable this_ where this_.name=? 
group by nvl2(val, 'Y', 'N'), this_.name, this_.val, this_.nbr, this_.proj, this_.loc
```

Another way is to use `@Formula` annotation on a new field in your entity.

In my case, I have added this field in the `CoalesceDemo` class

```
@Formula("nvl2(val, 'Y', 'N')")
public String decodedVal;
```

And use this in the Criteria query as below:

```
List<CoalesceDemo> list = session.createCriteria(CoalesceDemo.class).
    setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.sum("sub"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("name"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("val"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("nbr"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("proj"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("decodedVal"))
            .add(Projections.groupProperty("loc")))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("name", "value")).list();
```

And this results in a query as below:

```
select this_.name as y0_, this_.loc as y1_, this_.nbr as y2_, this_.proj as y3_, sum(this_.sub) as y4_, 
this_.name as y5_, this_.val as y6_, this_.nbr as y7_, this_.proj as y8_, 
nvl2(this_.val, 'Y', 'N') as y9_, this_.loc as y10_ from CoalesceTable this_ where this_.name=? 
group by this_.name, this_.val, this_.nbr, this_.proj, nvl2(this_.val, 'Y', 'N'), this_.loc
```

See if this helps and you may want to test it with against your data.